# Displaying an ACF list of users

Tags: custom-field, array, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a custom field using ACF to display the editors of a page (this may be a comma separated list of a few) including a link to their archive, but all I'm getting is a plain text 'Array'. Could someone help me get this right? For some reason I'm not finding the right info through the documentation.

```
if(get_field('editor')) { echo ', edited by ' . get_field('editor') . '';}
$values = get_field('editor'); if($values) { foreach($values as $value) {
echo ' ' . $value . ','; } }
```

Comment: use `print_r()` instead of `echo` to see the contents of the array. That's purely a PHP question, hence off-topic.

Comment: OK, thanks for that tip, but how can I extract the information I need to produce the link?

Comment: It depends what information are being retrieved... are you retrieving an array of IDs?

Comment: This is what I'm getting: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [user_firstname] => Name [user_lastname] => Surname [nickname] => admin [user_nicename] => admin [display_name] => Name Surname [user_email] => name.surname@mail.com [user_url] => [user_registered] => 2013-07-10 10:41:07 [user_description] => [user_avatar] => ) )`

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_author_posts_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url) or [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta):

```
$values = get_field( 'editor' );
if ( $values ) {
  $editors = array();
  foreach ( $values as $value ) {
    $link = get_author_posts_url( $value['ID'] ); //get the url
    $nicename = $value['user_nicename'];
    $editors[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $link, $nicename ); //create a link for each author
  }
  echo 'Edited by: ' . implode( ',', $editors );
}
```

Comment: Is `$values` is a string of author names seperated by comma? If yes then where is `$values = explode(',',$values)`

Comment: According to [this comment](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106854/displaying-an-acf-list-of-users/106970?noredirect=1#comment148779_106854), it's an array...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Co-Authors Plus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/) WordPress plugin.

**Features:**

1).Assign multiple bylines to posts, pages, and custom post types via a search-as-you-type input box.

2).Co-authored posts appear on a co-author's archive page and in their feed. Co-authors may edit the posts they are associated with.

3).Co-authors who are contributors may only edit posts if they have not been published (as is core behavior).

4).Add writers as bylines without creating WordPress user accounts. Simply [create a guest author profile](http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/add-guest-bylines-to-your-content-with-co-authors-plus/) for the writer and assign the byline as you normally would.

5).On the frontend, use the [Co-Authors Plus template tags](http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/incorporate-co-authors-plus-template-tags-into-your-theme/) to list co-authors anywhere you'd normally list the author.

**Note:**

[Post Authors Post Link Shortcode](https://gist.github.com/billerickson/4061770) for this plugin

Comment: Thanks, but I also have a seperate field for translator. This plugin is not quite what I'm looking for.